Как загрузить файл в консоли
Пытался как то так:
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://f52.workupload.com/download/myprYfDZD63", 
"C:Userstipo5.ZDEBRYDownloadsText.txt")

Через PowerShell
Но у меня выдаёт, что-то не так. Можете помочь как загрузить?
При заходе на сайт оно само должно скачать.
Можно так же попробовать использовать сайт workupload
Ну или же f52.workupload

Я уж не знаю, что там шерстить - первая ссылка в гугле: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225598/downloading-a-file-with-powershell

@AlexanderSt можете перевести и оформить как ответ на руСО, также можно ассоциировать с предложенным вами ответом на енСО

ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51225598/10562663

Вольный перевод ответа на enSO
Invoke-WebRequest имеет параметр для сохранения результата в файл: -OutFile
Invoke-WebRequest $myDownloadUrl -OutFile c:\file.ext

Если нужна предварительная авторизация:
Invoke-WebRequest $myAuthUrl /* данные, необходимые для авторизации */ -SessionVariable MySession
Invoke-WebRequest $myDownloadUrl -WebSession $MySession

Чтобы определить макет формы, в которой происходит вход в систему, можно использовать возвращаемый объект Invoke-WebRequests. Он соберет информацию о формах и полях HTML (возможно, только для Windows). Количество действий при входе в систему может варьироваться в зависимости от того, активна или нет двухфакторная аутентификация. Возможно, вы можете создать какую-то секретную ссылку на ваш файл, которая не требует Auth, или, возможно, google позволит вам создать приватный токен доступа, который можно отправить вместе с запросом в Authorization-Header.

мои +1, еще можно сделать ассоциацию. То есть все кто будут определены enSO как русскоговорящие увидят сообщение, что данный ответ есть на ruSO

@Dmitry, если вы можете эту ассоциацию проставить - проставьте пожалуйста, а если еще и меня научите, как это сделать - буду вам благодарен

Да, поставил под вопросом. Можете пользоваться в дальнейшем. Все что нужно - это написать ассоциация: и добавить ссылку на вопрос на енСО в комментарии.
